# Why can't specrunner.html parse TypeScript-generated spec.js?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, jasmine

I'm working within a Jasmine framework in VS Code, containing TypeScript files (`.ts`)
and their corresponding specs (`.spec`). After running `npm build test`, the expected JavaScript files
(`.js` and `.spec.js`) are generated. This is generated code from `.spec.js`:

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
        });
};
import { greet } from './helloWorld';
describe('greet function', () => {
    it('should return "Hello, World!"', () => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
        const message = yield greet();
        expect(message).toBe('Hello, World!');
    }));
});
```

However, `specrunner.html` encounters an error "**Error during loading:
Unexpected token**" when attempting to load the generated `spec.js` file.